# Does building turrets on a planet put adjacent planets on alert?

Tags: ai-war-fleet-command

Say I go to an AI planet and attack the ships there, but leave the command station and warp gate alone. Now I take a mobile builder there, and build turrets (it's adjacent to one of my planets, so it has supply) and other defensive buildings, to defend the entrance to my wormhole. Does this put adjacent planets on alert as if I had taken the planet from the AI, or do the adjacent planets just sit there blissfully unaware?